# Easiest way to add privacy policy with my android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, privacy-policy

I am developing an android app that stores highscores locally and via google play services. I am also integrating Google AdMob into my app. My question is, what is the easiest way to add a privacy policy when signing into google play services when first opening the app and on the homepage when downloading the app?

Thank you for your time in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Create an HTML page and link to it. This might be required since you'll need a Privacy Policy URL to submit on Google Play Store.
- Embed the Privacy Policy in your app in a view.

You have plenty of options where to show the policy in your app:

1. **On your app profile page from Google Play Store:**

   [image: via TermsFeed]

   To do so:

   - Log into your Google Play Developer Console.
   - Select All Applications
   - Select the application
   - Click Store Listing
   - Enter the public URL of your Privacy Policy at the Privacy Policy field:
2. **On your app login/welcome screen.**

   Example from Waze app:

   [image: via TermsFeed]
   [image: via TermsFeed]
3. **In your app's Settings/Help menu:**

   Example from eBay:

   [image: via TermsFeed]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the privacy policy in a HTML page on your server and then link to it on the PlayStore store listing page. And also open it in a WebView inside your app.